# Read all the content from .config file & insert into a dictionary with python

Tags: python, dictionary

I there any way to insert all the content of config file & insert into a dictionary.

Config file is a nest dictionary:

```
[A]
x:1
y:2
z:3
[B]
a:4
b:5
c:6
```

Is there any way to to get the details as
`{A:{x:1,y:2,z:3}, B:{a:4,b:5,c:6}}`.

Above is a sample .Can we do this with generic(not specific to this config file)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html may help.

Comment: Of course there are ways. What trouble are you having with your way?

Comment: Where is your code ? What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

Use [**`ConfigParser`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html):

```
>>> s = """
[A]
x:1
y:2
z:3
[B]
a:4
b:5
c:6"""

>>> from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
>>> from StringIO import StringIO

>>> parser = ConfigParser()
>>> parser.readfp(StringIO(s))
>>> {section: {key: value
               for key, value in parser.items(section)}
     for section in parser.sections()}
{'A': {'x': '1', 'y': '2', 'z': '3'}, 'B': {'a': '4', 'b': '5', 'c': '6'}}
```